# i want to save product information and images for each product variant

Tags: php, laravel

The code i provided is used to save product information and images for each product variant. The issue i am facing is that the same images are being saved for each variant, whereas you want unique images per product variant in every color.

`$product_code = uniqid('#');

```
    $product = new Product;
    $product->brand_id = $request->brand_id;
    $product->category_id = $request->category_id;
    $product->subcategory_id = $request->subcategory_id;
    $product->subsubcategory_id = $request->subsubcategory_id;
    $product->product_name_en = $request->product_name_en;
    $product->product_name_ar = $request->product_name_ar;
    $product->product_slug_en = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $request->product_name_en));
    $product->product_slug_ar = str_replace(' ', '-', $request->product_name_ar);
    $product->product_code = $product_code;
    $product->product_tags_en = $request->product_tags_en;
    $product->product_tags_ar = $request->product_tags_ar;
    $product->product_weight = $request->product_weight;
    $product->short_descp_en = $request->short_descp_en;
    $product->short_descp_ar = $request->short_descp_ar;
    $product->long_descp_en = $request->long_descp_en;
    $product->long_descp_ar = $request->long_descp_ar;
    $product->hot_deals = $request->hot_deals;
    $product->featured = $request->featured;
    $product->special_offer = $request->special_offer;
    $product->special_deals = $request->special_deals;
    $product->product_thumbnail = $save_url;
    $product->save();
    $product_id = $product->id;

    // create an array to store all the images for each variant
    $variantImages = [];

    foreach ($request->color_en as $i => $color) {
        $variantData = [
            'color_en' => $color,
            'size_en' => $request->size_en[$i],
            'size_ar' => $request->size_ar[$i],
            'selling_price' => $request->selling_price[$i],
            'discount_price' => $request->discount_price[$i],
            'product_qty' => $request->product_qty[$i],
        ];

        // Create a new variant
        $variant = new ProductVariant;
        $variant->product_id = $product_id;
        $variant->color_en = $variantData['color_en'];
        $variant->size_en = $variantData['size_en'];
        $variant->size_ar = $variantData['size_ar'];
        $variant->selling_price = $variantData['selling_price'];
        $variant->discount_price = $variantData['discount_price'];
        $variant->product_qty = $variantData['product_qty'];
        $variant->save();

        if ($request->hasFile('multi_img')) {
            $images = $request->file('multi_img');
            $variantImages[$i] = []; // create an array to store the images for this variant

            foreach ($images as $img) {
                $name_gen = uniqid() . '_' . time() . '_' . $variant->id . '_' . $i . '.' . $img->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $save_dir = public_path('upload/products/multi-image');
                if (!file_exists($save_dir)) {
                    mkdir($save_dir, 0777, true);
                }
                if (is_writable($save_dir)) {
                    $photo = Image::make($img);
                    // resize and save the image
                    $photo->resize(800, null, function ($constraint) {
                        $constraint->aspectRatio();
                    });
                    $photo->save($save_dir . '/' . $name_gen);
                    $save_url = 'upload/products/multi-image/' . $name_gen;
                }
                // create the image record and save its variant id
                // $multiImage = new ProductVariantImage;
                // $multiImage->product_variant_id = $variant->id;
                // $multiImage->photo_name = $save_url;
                // $multiImage->save();

                // add the image path to the array for this variant
                $variantImages[$i][] =  [
                    'photo_name' => $save_url,
                    'product_variant_id' => $variant->id,
                ];
            }
            // ProductVariantImage::insert($variantImages[$i]);
        }
    }

    // dd($variantImages);



    foreach ($variantImages as $i => $images) {
        foreach ($images as $multiImage) {
            $multiImage = new ProductVariantImage;
            $multiImage->product_variant_id = $variant->id;
            $multiImage->photo_name = $$save_url;
            $multiImage->save();
        }
    }`
```

i want unique images per product variant in every color.

Comment: <input type="file" name="multi_img[]" multiple>

Answer (score 0):

There are some things wrong in your codes. Try changing it to:

```
 //... 
   foreach ($variantImages as $i => $images) {
        foreach ($images as $image) {
           $multiImage = new ProductVariantImage;
           $multiImage->product_variant_id = $image['product_variant_id'];
           $multiImage->photo_name = $image['photo_name'];
           $multiImage->save();
         }
    }
  //...
```

Comment: I changed it to your provide code , and it is the same issue save all images for each product variant . 
it not  unique .

Comment: You want that a varian_id will have a different image, right?

Comment: i want unique images per product variant in every color.

for examples
1- i have red color inside ProductVariant model as you see in the code  and i have many images uploaded  to that color .
2- i have blue color  with same example of  (1) with deferent images.

but  the issues are saving all images for all   ProductVariant  it not unique